# setup color in VBA

Tags: vba, colors

I tried below but doesn't work...

Column O for Home or Office would like to reveal if Column O is Home then Column P will filling colour

```
Sub colour()

    If Range("O:O").Value = "Home" Then
        Range("P:P").Interior.Color = RGB(222, 244, 180)

    End If


End Sub
```

Thanks.

Comment: You need to loop through the cells in column O and test if the `Value` is `Home`. What you want can be easily done using Conditional Formatting though, must you use VBA?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Dim i as integar

for i = 2 to range("O" & Rows.Count).end(3)(1).row
        if range("O" & i).value="Home" then range("P" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(222, 244, 180)
Next i
```

Comment: Typo for `integar` and also since you are using it to iterate rows, you should use `Long` type to avoid overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Using conditional formatting, this can be done very easily: just check the cells in the "P" column you want to highlight, and use conditional formatting, based on the formula `=$O1="Home"`, as in following screenshot:

[image]